# Duplicate entries in Field History tracking of record

Tags: apex, history-tracking

I have set a datetime field (Tcc_First_Action_Date_Time__c) for history tracking and in my trigger on certain condition this field is updated. Part of my trigger where this field is updating:-

```
  if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
     Lead LeadBeforeUpdate = Trigger.oldMap.get( ld.Id );
     if( LeadBeforeUpdate.OwnerId == TCCqueue.Id && members.containsKey(ld.ownerid) ){
        ld.Tcc_Owner_Acceptance_Date__c  = date.today();

      }
      if( ld.Tcc_First_Action_Date_Time__c != datetime.now() && members.containsKey(CUser.id) && ( LeadBeforeUpdate.status != ld.status || (String.Isempty(ld.TCC_Attempts__c) != TRUE && LeadBeforeUpdate.TCC_Attempts__c != ld.TCC_Attempts__c) ) )  {
        ld.Tcc_First_Action_Date__c = date.today();
        ld.Tcc_First_Action_Date_Time__c = datetime.now();
        ld.Tcc_Actor__c = CUser.firstname+' '+CUser.lastname;  
      }
     } else if(Trigger.isInsert){
       if(ld.Tcc_First_Action_Date_Time__c != datetime.now() && members.containsKey(CUser.id) && ld.Status != 'Not Contacted' )
         ld.Tcc_First_Action_Date__c = date.today();
         ld.Tcc_First_Action_Date_Time__c = datetime.now();
         ld.Tcc_Actor__c = CUser.firstname+' '+CUser.lastname;        
     }
```

But for some records this field is getting changed twice with exactly same value. i.e. i am getting 2 field history records with old and new values exactly same.
[image]

In above img entry1(red underliened) is correct but there is duplicate entry 2(blue underlined) which i don't want.
So anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try setting `System.debug` in that `if( LeadBeforeUpdate.OwnerId == TCCqueue.Id && members.containsKey(ld.ownerid)` statement. You'll come to know whether `Tcc_Owner_Acceptance_Date__c` gets updated from here or from somewhere else as well.

Comment: Most probably your trigger is getting called recursively. Are you performing a update operation on Lead in the trigger?

Comment: Hi Rohit, field i am tracking is : Tcc_First_Action_Date_Time__c

Comment: Hi Santanu, Yes i am performing DML operations in this trigger....and yes this is most probable answer....but is there any way we can stop 2nd duplicate entry

Comment: You have to be really careful with stopping recursive triggers. If you stop them you could expirence issues when dataloading or running batchjobs. I think that you should reconsider if this is the correct place to do it or should it be together with the logic that triggers the logic. You could also consider if the trigger should use before or after, with a before trigger you would not need to do a DML.